# Error GET Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Today, Google places API stopped working on my site. Yesterday, it was working just fine. When I call it, I get following error in developer's console:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?1slux&4scs-CZ&9sgeocode&15e3&key=AIzaSyCe8-UQIQuXtaQ5xVOqtwnCtZOjDtXj4Co&callback=_xdc_._8rz5bv&token=109805 net::ERR_ABORTED
```

The problem isn't in Google maps API itself, because that works just fine (without the Places). If I take fresh code snipper from [Google website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=es), it is still not working, as you can see [here](http://gmaps.ipdive.com/index2.html). So the problem isn't in my code, but in the API itself. I checked my project on Google site and the API is enabled, so it should work. Maybe it's connected to my API key? I haven't tried creating a new one, I don't want to have too many of them.

Comment: Please add you solution as an answer, see [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: After approximately one hour (from posting this), it started working again. Apparently a problem on Google side. So if you have the same problem:

1. Go to your Google account and check in API manager if the Google Places API service is enabled.
2. If it is enabled, wait and be patient. Hopefully it will fix by itself.

Comment: Yes, consult this post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143691/google-maps-places-autocomplete-502-error). Or, consult this [google issue blog](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/Oo6jvTEgyPs). I hope that it is helping you :)