# google.maps.places.Autocomplete 502 error

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am using the google.maps.places.Autocomplete API and this morning I was getting a 502 Bad Gateway error. It lasted about 10 minutes and started working again. I assume this had to do with the service being unavailable.

I was wondering how I can error handle when this happens. My (javascript) autocomplete code looks like this:

```
$('#StartAddress').change(function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(startAutocomplete, 'place_changed');
    return false;
});


var source, destination;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService;
if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    // set up places autocomplete
    var start = document.getElementById('StartAddress');
    var startAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(start);

    var end = document.getElementById('EndAddress');
    var endAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(end);

    // add the places auto complete listener for when the values change
    startAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        var startAddress = $('#StartAddress').val();
        var endAddress = $('#EndAddress').val();
        if (endAddress && startAddress) {

            GetRoute(startAddress, endAddress, false);
        }
    });

    endAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        var endAddress = $('#EndAddress').val();
        var startAddress = $('#StartAddress').val();
        if (endAddress && startAddress) {

            GetRoute(startAddress, endAddress, false);
        }
    });
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': false });
}
```

The GetRoute(startAddress, endAddress, false) function is a call to the google.maps.Map and that works fine. It was only the autocomplete service that was down.

Also, is it possible this error occurred because I am using the developer key instead of production? Like the googles dev environment is much more resource limited?

Comment: Your question may be: How can I get all the errors with google maps api? Then, you can find if a 502 error and reload your geolocation system. (However, I do not find a way to do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service was down this time. Try again now.

Comment: Right, it is working again but I want to trap when the service is down and at let the user know. I want to know if the service api has a status code that you catch. It appears that it doesn't. I also wanted to know if the production instance of this service is less prone to this happening.

Comment: I was thinking something like: if(google.maps.Autocomplete === 'object') or in the service binding: endAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function (response, status), but there are no response/status params for addListener that I can see.

Comment: To be honest, I never seen this service down before. Don't think is worth the effort to handle this case, but sure you can do it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info

Comment: Gonna mark as the answer since you knew the service was down.